# Null space of bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

I am doing a practice exam for functional analysis I have no idea what to here.

For a: Since $N(\phi)^\bot$ is nonempty, let $f\in N(\phi)^\bot$ with $\phi(f)=\alpha$. Then $g=\frac{1}{\alpha}f$ is also in the same set and has $\phi(g)=1$.

But how do I approach b and c? I have no idea which theorem to use here except that the $N(\phi)$ and $N(\phi)^\bot$ make up a direct sum of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b), verify that $N(\phi)^\perp$ has dimension $1$ (this is a well-known fact from linear algebra) and decompose $f$ onto $N(\phi)$ and $N(\phi)^\perp$.

For item (c), take $\mathcal{H}=L^2(0,1)$ and the linear functional $\phi\colon h\mapsto\int_0^{1/4}h(x)dx$ (it is continuous by Hölder's inequality, for example). Use the procedure of your solution to item (a) to find $h\in\mathcal{N}(\phi)^\perp$ such that $\phi(h)=1$. By item (b), it has minimum $L^2$-norm.

Further hint: In item (c), there is still the problem to find some element of $\mathcal{N}(\phi)^\perp$. So recall Riesz' Lemma: There exists a unique $t_0\in L^2(0,1)$ such that
$$\phi(h)=\langle h,t_0\rangle=\int_0^1 h(x)t_0(x)dx$$
for all $h\in L^2(0,1)$. Can you find such $t_0$? Is it clear that $t_0\in \mathcal{N}(\phi)^\perp$?

Comment: I saw your comment earlier. Why is f=-g not a counter example to b?

Comment: @QuestionMaker Because $\phi(-g)=-1$, and not $1$.

Comment: For $b$: Null space is closed so $(N^\perp)\perp=N$ so that if $<x,y>=0$ means at least one of both must be in $N$. So I could say $f=x+y$ and $g=z+\alpha y$ for a constant $\alpha$

Comment: @QuestionMaker No, this is not true (e.g. $H=\mathbb{R}^2$, $\phi(x_1,x_2)=x_1$, $x=(1,1)$ and $y=(1,-1)$. Then $\langle x,y\rangle=0$, but neither $x$ nor $y$ belong to $N(\phi)$ nor to $N(\phi)^\perp$). You should try using the definition of $N(\phi)$, not just that it is a closed subspace. In fact the fact that it is closed does not matter at all.

Comment: @QuestionMaker What I mean is that the following is true and you should be able to prove it with basic linear algebra: If $V$ is any vector space over any field $k$, $\phi\colon V\to k$ is $k$-linear, and $V$ is being decomposed as $V=N(\phi)\oplus W$, where $N(\phi)=\phi^{-1}(0)$ is the null space of $\phi$, then $\dim_k W=1$.

Comment: Also you say for (c) that question (b) guarantees it has a minimal norm, but (b) says that $||f||>||g||$ for all other $g$, doesn't that mean its a maximal norm?

Comment: @QuestionMaker No. Item (b) says that $\Vert f\Vert>\Vert \Vert$ for all other $f$!!. $g$ is fixed by item (a).

Comment: Oh wow, it was completely unclear to me that they meant by $g$ that they had fixed $g$ from a. Let me take a look now

Comment: @QuestionMaker Yes, the question lacks some clarity. A better wording would be "(b)Let $g$ be as in (a), and let $f\in\mathcal{H}$ such that $\phi(f)=1$ and $f\neq g$. Prove that $\Vert f\Vert>\Vert g\Vert$."

Comment: I see how to proceed given that the space perpendicular to the null space has dimension 1. How to prove this fact?

Comment: @QuestionMaker Suppose $v\in N(\phi)^\perp$ is nonzero. Then $\phi(v)\neq 0$ (why?). If $w\in N(\phi)^\perp$ is any other element, then $v-\frac{\phi(v)}{\phi(w)}w$ belong to both $N(\phi)^\perp$ and to $N(\phi)$, so $w=\frac{\phi(w)}{\phi(v)}v$. Therefore $v$ generates $N(\phi)^\perp$.